# Markov's Inequality

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ has variance $\operatorname {Var}(X) = 9$ and expectation $E(X) = 2$. Furthermore, the value of $X$ is never greater than $10$. Given this information, provide either a proof or a counterexample for the following statements.

$$Pr[X =2]>0.$$

I tried to do this by saying $Y = 10 - X$ and use Markov's inequality.

I did 
$$Pr[ 10 - X \leq 2] \leq E(10) - E(X) / 2$$
$$Pr[10-X \leq 2] \leq 8/4  $$
$$Pr[10-X \leq 2] \leq 4$$
Then, when $X = 2$, the $Pr[X=2]$ should be 4. Therefore the above statement is true? Am I using Markov's inequality correctly in this problem?

Sorry I just realized my solution is not possible because we cannot have a probability of , but how can we possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As a counter-example (there will be many more), consider

$$Pr(X = -1) = \frac12$$
$$Pr\left(X = 5\right) = \frac12$$

If the numbers have to be non-negative, consider 
$$Pr(X = 0) = \frac9{13}$$
$$Pr\left(X = \frac{13}{2}\right) = \frac4{13}$$

Comment: Oh, I thought about it so it would be false?

Comment: Looks like it.  You can also find continuous distributions with this mean and variance